# Allow '&' sign in URL (mod rewrite)

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is there anyway I can allow the "&" sign as a variable in the URL?

My current rule for tags is:

```
 RewriteRule ^tag/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?section=home&tag=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Tags like "cool" and "nice45" work. But "this&that" doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use both `[B]` and `[NE]` flags :

```
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?section=home&tag=$1 [L,QSA,NC,B,NE]
```

- `[B]` will escape `&` before applying the transformation,
  then it won't be caught as `tag=this` and `that=`
- `[NE]` will avoid `&` to be escaped a second time after the transformation

**[> mod-rewrite flags documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags)**

Comment: You are officially Awesome :)